# aws ssm send-command not working with special characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am able to send simple commands to some of my Amazon ec2 instances. For example:

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids "${instanceid}" --parameters commands=["cd /home/ec2-user","mkdir -p test"]
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids "${instanceid}" --parameters commands=["cd /home/ec2-user","sudo chmod 777 test"]
```

I can also echo text to a sample file:

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids "${instanceid}" --parameters commands=["cd /home/ec2-user","echo thisvalue = temp >> test/sample.txt"]
```

However, if I use a bracket as part of the command / text, for example:

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids "${instanceid}" --parameters commands=["cd /home/ec2-user","echo [default] > test/sample.txt"]
```

I get the following error:

Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Expected: ',', received: '>' for input:

When the text is wrapped in brackets [] the issue is thrown. Therefore, the question boils down to: how am I able to pass 'special' characters through the aws ssm send-command function?

Comment: May be try to escape special characters by using a backslash?

Comment: If I do: [\default this works but only gives me [default (without the closing bracket). But if I do [\default]\ it will not work at all.

Comment: try `\[default\]`

Comment: same issue as original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids "${instanceid}" --parameters commands='["cd /home/ec2-user","echo [\default\] > test/sample.txt"]'
```

In other words, put single quotes around the command option and escape the brackets properly.

Comment: can you please tell how to re syntax the below command ```aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "i-0e4b1e415c969903f" --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --parameters commands="runuser -l pranayama -c 'cd /opt/laravel/pranayama && git branch'" ```
facing ```Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Expected: ',', received: ''' for input: commands=``` while executing the above command. can you please tell how can i escape the single quote inside the command argument